# Manipulation of Array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have Array of order in State of my Components.
like order: [Navbar, Header,Services, About],
This array store value that which component will be called first. I want to swap arry elements so that I can re render my webpage with new order. Can't find anything to manipulate this array.

Comment: What metric do you want to use to reorder them? You need to provide some code showing what you have tried so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: Please post actual code, preferably a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to swap the values to create new order. It doesn't matter however you decide to do that as long as you have the index of two elements that you want to swap. The easiest way to swap in javascript is to use cool ES6 Feature,

Let's suppose you want to swap Header and About. Then the index would be 1 and 3 so the code will be.

```
let arr = ['Navbar', 'Header','Services', 'About'];
[arr[1],arr[3]] = [arr[3], arr[1]];
```

Now if you check the arr variable the output will be

```
["Navbar", "About", "Services", "Header"]
```

Comment: If this answers your question can you mark it as correct, so that other users can know this solves the problem. If it doesn't can you raise questions so that this problem gets solved.